# Check if azure application has been granted consent on customer's tenant?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

Is there a way to check if admin has granted consent for application to access customers tenants?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to check if whether the application has been granted permissions (a configuration) to access customer tenants  or   the admin's action of granting consent has been done?

Comment: The first one: whether the application has been granted permissions to access customer tenants.

I keep getting Authorization_IdentityNotFound error ("The identity of the calling application could not be established") while trying to list tenant's users via Microsoft Graph API (app has all needed permissions set on this API). I want to rule out possibility that somehow my app is not authorized to access that tenant.

Comment: Hi,@menth0l . Yes , you can. Go to Azure portal> Azure Active Directory > Enterprise applictions.  If the application has been granted permissions, it would occurs in Enterprise applications.

Comment: I assume you meant to check Azure Portal after login as admin not as customer?

So I checked and my Web App / API app (from "App registrations") is not there. If that's the case then what do i need to do effectively grant consent for this app?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46360206/how-can-i-test-if-admin-consent-has-already-been-given/46414012#46414012

Comment: HI,@menth0l . Yes,you need to login Azure portal with admin account.  If the app is not on your `app registrations` of the admin account, it may be deleted. Just contact your admin of your directory for this issue.

Comment: No, what i meant was that my apps are registered but not visible in Enterprise apps. According to your statement it means that they weren't given admin consent? Clicking "Grant permissions" on them changes nothing.

Comment: @Daniel Dobalian: i used the method from your link to list all permissions via `oauth2PermissionGrants` call - my apps wheren't on that list. How to fix it?

Comment: Maybe this article will help: https://joonasw.net/view/the-grant-requires-admin-permission