# How to verify Admin consent for AAD Application?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Is there a way to find out if an admin consent is enabled for particular application. In my organization only IT has access to enable the admin consent but is there a way to verify if the consent was enabled or not.

Comment: There is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46360206/how-can-i-test-if-admin-consent-has-already-been-given/46414012#46414012  Hope this helps!

Comment: In addition to that answer, granted application permissions can be found from service principal's appRoleAssignments. This article might help: https://joonasw.net/view/the-grant-requires-admin-permission

Answer (score 0):

If you registered App in the above azure portal then there is a way to find out:

If you are trying to grant the permission for the app you will get the message like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qoqF.png).i think this may useful for you.

Comment: I am not admin on the AAD and once I ask admin's to enable consent or multi-tenancy on a app they takes the ownership of the app. So I don't have access to grant permission.